# Regex replace for wrapping numbers with pound signs

Tags: php, regex

I have numbers wrapped with curly brackets in my text i.e. `{123}` or `{456ABC}`. I also have numbers not wrapped with brackets i.e. `789`. I want to match these not-yet wrapped numbers and use PHP's preg_replace to wrap them with pound signs i.e. `#789#`. The numbers usually range from 1-3 digits.

```
print(preg_replace('/\d+/','#$0#',
'1) I can count to 2997510. You can only count to {456ABC}.'));
```

Desired output:

```
#1#) I can count to #2997510#. You can only count to {456ABC}.
```

What regex would match the numbers? I've tried negative lookahead `(?![^\{])\d+` and `[^\{](\d+)[^\{]`

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: `[^\{](\d+)[^\{]` and some negative lookahead combinations

Comment: `(?![^\{])\d+` like this one

Comment: do you know the amount of numbers in the whole string?

Comment: It varies, generally 1-3 digits.

Comment: @skibulk: Usually, you want to add the additional information you put in comments here to your question instead; it makes it easier for people to understand your question.

Comment: @RobertP Well that makes a lot of sense! I'm going to add that right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(\A|[^{\d])(\d[\d\w]*)(\z|[^\}\d\z])` should do it for you.

Used like:

```
print(preg_replace('/(\A|[^{\d])(\d[\d\w]*)(\z|[^\}\d\z])/','$1#$2#$3',
'1) I can count to 2997510. You can only count to {456ABC}.'));
```

Explanation:

- The first part `(\A|[^{\d])` matches either the start of the input (to catch numbers at the beginning of the string) or a non `{` or digit. This part ensures the numbers aren't already wrapped.
- The second part `(\d[\d\w]*)` does the actual matching of the number. It matches anything that starts with a digit followed by any number of contiguous digits or letters.
- The last part `(\z|[^\}\d\z])` is analogous to the first part, except looks for the end of the input.
- Because this regular expression can capture a character before and after the target number, it is important to add those characters back in using the 1st and 3rd matched subgroups (as seen in the PHP example.

Comment: I'm choosing your answer because the \A and \Z implementation is is brilliant. Also for explaining the regex compenents. I had it in my head that I needed to replace just the number with a $0, but capturing and joining the matching characters on either side is thinking out of the box. I learned a lot from this; Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`[^\{\dA-F]([A-F\d]+)[^\}\dA-F]`

(I'm assuming that you're trying to match hex numbers with capital letters; if not, just alter the character class appropriately.)

The extra `\d`'s are in the negative character classes because if they aren't there, then the engine will avoid brackets by cutting off the outermost digits. For instance, `[^\{](\d+)[^\}]` will match the 456 in {34567}.

The number itself is "group 1" of any match. If you need the entire match itself to be the number, use a lookahead and a lookbehind:

`(?<=[^\{\dA-F])([A-F\d]+)(?=[^\}\dA-F])`

Here is a Perl-style search-and-replace to insert the `#`'s, with no lookahead or lookbehind:

`s/([^\{\dA-F])([A-F\d]+)([^\}\dA-F])/$1#$2#$3/g`

Comment: Doesn't account for the alphabetic characters, i.e. `456ABC`.

Comment: This is matching the leading space and trailing period: "# 2997510.#"

Comment: The whole thing should match the characters immediately left and right of the number, yes, but the parentheses group the number, so if all you're looking for is a match, you can get it that way.

Comment: Edited it to include some applications of the original regex that might better fit your use-case.